# None of the answers to the 2018 survey question about responsibility for unethical behavior are correct

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2018

One of the questions of the survey was :

[image: Screenshot: Who is responsible for unethical code?]

But to me, this question has a logical answer.

Everybody who participated **intentionally** is responsible. If somebody participated unintentionally, then he can't be blamed: he didn't even know whether it was bad. Then, logically, every single person who was **conscious** of the unethical aspect of the mischievous code, but still decided to shut up and go for it, is to be blamed.

In short: you are aware it's unethical, but you don't care and it goes on, you're guilty.

And I think it's also the case from a law point of view. The one that started the plan is the criminal. Everybody who follows, while knowing how wrong it is, are partners in crime.

Now the question is about which person is responsible, but it can't be answered.

Maybe all of them are responsible. In fact, as I said, everyone is who participated intentionally.

**EDIT :**

C Perkins comment below may better explain my concern.

Anyway, as you can see, and I was expecting it, there is nothing to acknowledge from the results of this question.

[image]

Remove it for the next survey ?

Comment: But what if I am intentionally _un_-conscious of whether what I'm writing is unethical or not?

Comment: Was this question mandatory? I don't know if all questions in the survey are mandatory. If it was mandatory, it shouldn't have been, or at least it should have been given a "Not sure" option. Other than that, it's there to solicit the views of those who do believe the question can be answered, based on their views. They don't call it a survey for nothing.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this Meta post. What kind of responses are you looking for?

Comment: @JoshCaswell if you have a clear point of view on this question, good for you. But I do not. I'm forced to answer something, none of the option is even close to my opinion ... "Someone else" option is also problematic. Maybe I should not care at all with the survey ?

Comment: If we wanted to know legally who would be responsible, we wouldn't need a survey question.

Comment: It's a silly, abstract question with no meaningful answer.  I could **easily** describe unique situations were each answer is the best and where the other answers would be irrelevant.  Likewise, there are definitely stories where all choices would be mutually responsible.  Sure, it's easy to just wave hands and says "it's just a survey", but stupid questions like this just diminish the legitimacy of the whole survey.  It feels like a lame political survey question which only purpose is get blood flowing and make you feel like you're contributing to something useful ... but not really.

Comment: _"believe [..] ultimately most responsible"_, it isn't asking for a statement of fact, but for an opinion. I'm not 100% sure, but I think I just skipped this one by not providing an answer.

Comment: @CPerkins thank you for actually understanding my concern. At least four other persons understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The one that started the plan is the criminal. Everybody who follows,
> while knowing how wrong it is, are partners in crime.

True, but while one person gets charged with the original crime the others might only get charged with aiding and abetting or being an accomplice after the fact. I think the point of the question was: Who is the **main** person responsible when this happens? Who's most at fault?

> Everybody who participated **intentionally** is responsible.

This is more of an aside but re-reading the original survey question, I'm not sure we were even supposed to assume that the code was meant to be unethical. It said "accomplishes something unethical", not that the original idea was unethical.

Comment: Interesting, after reading your answer it gets even more complicated to answer the survey question, but knowing I could have skipped is satisfying.

Answer (score 6):

Given that laws change, and that "ethical" code is often a moving target (for instance, someone that writes code for a targeting system of a Predator drone used to drop munitions on cities, versus someone who writes code to detect and fingerprint child pornography to later block the images and arrest anyone involved with it), I personally feel that asking people who is responsible for "unethical" code is a fair survey question.

If nothing else, we can take the temperature of the room to see who everyone feels is ultimately responsible.  That's what surveys *do*.

Comment: So i'm going to answer randomly? The last option I have is to check "someone else" and it's not even true... Believe me i'd rather not have scratched my head half an hour and end up with a meta post to brother you. The "not sure" or "skip" option would have been great.

Comment: In principle I don't disagree.  However, in software development there are few others left to hold accountable for code besides the people listed in this survey question.

Comment: Yes i understand that "Someone else" is also a correct answer... So what to do ? I can't check them all either.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Choose whichever one you feel is most applicable to your viewpoint.  If you feel none of them are suitably close, then don't provide an answer at all.

Comment: @Servy I could have actually skipped the question? It was radio button so I though I was forced to answer... All's good if I can skip, it was not obvious to me but the correct action for me would have been to skip this one question.

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out: It was hard to make sense of the question in the survey in the given form. The fact that it was included in the survey was likely a side-effect of the revivial of the [Trolley problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trolley_problem) due to the advent of ... "self-driving cars", "self-driving" cars, self-"driving" cars or "self"-driving cars.

<sup>(Not sure where to put the quotes there...)</sup>

Sure, this is speculation, and beyond the *reason*, one could still argue about the *purpose* of including it in the survey, causing further speculation - likely along the lines of "increasing awareness" or "fostering a discussion". The latter may be a goal that has been achieved, considering this question.

The answers may be "primarily opinion based", but at least I agree with the statement in the title, namely that none of the given answer options is "correct". However, I doubt that it can be boiled down to *participation* and *intention*.

What I tried to squeeze into the free-text field in a similar form:

The person who *uses* the code to accomplish something unethical is responsible. Up to that point, it's just code, which is totally unrelated to ethics.

Also see: [What ethical practices do students (as potential software engineers) need to be trained in?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/3070/what-ethical-practices-do-students-as-potential-software-engineers-need-to-be)

Comment: self-driving "cars"